# What does the "l0 r0" nomenclature mean on SlickGrid cells?

Tags: slickgrid

I'm trying to modify cells by adjusting the width of the "column", so I'm trying to figure out how SlickGrid classes and styles things.

I noticed each row has content like this:

```
<div class=​"slick-cell l0 r0">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"slick-cell l1 r1">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"slick-cell l2 r2">​…​</div>​
...
```

I thought maybe it was `l` for left (meaning column) and `r` for row, but both numbers change inside a single row. Anyone know what these classes are supposed to represent?

I see where it's set on line 1455 of `slick.grid.js`:

```
var cellCss = "slick-cell l" + cell + " r" + Math.min(columns.length - 1, cell + colspan - 1) +
```

I can't parse the intent of that math min statement though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `l` stands for "left" and `r` stands for "right".
SlickGrid dynamically generates the `.l<column>` and `.r<column>` CSS rules based on column widths.  The cells are absolutely positioned.  The `l<column>` rules specify the left coordinate, while the `r<column>` rules specify the right coordinate.  A typical cell will have both of them applied (ex. `l4 r4` for column 5).  This separation comes in handy for cells with colspan.  For example, if cell 4 spans 2 cells, it will have CSS `l4 r5` applied to it.

That said, you probably shouldn't mess with the grid's internals, and use the provided APIs instead :)